# Air native app won't exit

Tags: javascript, air, air-native-extension

I'm trying to control the exit of an Air Application, but can't get the application to actually quit.  I'm using Native processes with the extendedDesktop profile, and on exit am trying to run a script.  Right now it appears to exit, but the process is still running. I have to end the process through the task manager. Code below:

This is the event handler for an Exiting event.

function exit(){

```
//remove the exit event handler
air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.removeEventHandler(air.Event.EXITING,exit); 
//close the window
var winClosingEvent; 
var win = air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows[0]; 
closingEvent = new air.Event(air.Event.CLOSING,false,true); 
win.dispatchEvent(closingEvent); 
win.close();

//dispatch an exit event and force exit

var exitingEvent = new air.Event(air.Event.EXITING, false, false);
air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.dispatchEvent(exitingEvent);    
air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
```

}